# Raspberry Pi 3Bの解像度を4K(3840x2160)にしたい

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 3Bの解像度を4K(3840x2160)にしたいです。
Rasberry Pi 3Bで4K表示をする方法がわかりましたら教えてください。

やりたいこと
WEBブラウザを起動して、フルスクリーンで4K画像を表示したい。

試したこと
raspi-configで解像度の変更を試みましたが、
3840x2160の項目はありませんでした。

1920x1080で出力ができました。

Ubutu 18 LTSやDebianをインストールしたPCだと
3840x2160出力ができたことから、
Raspbianの設定でできるのではないか？と思っています。

下記を参考に、/boot/config.txtにhdmi_cvtなどの項目を記述しましたが
4K表示ができず、画面に信号がない状態になりました。

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=79330
tvserviceコマンドの実行結果も1920x1080のままです。

動作環境
Raspberry Pi3B
OS: Raspbian stretch
2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-full.img
テレビ：AQUOS LC-50US45 [50インチ]

RP3Bで4Kで出力した事がある方がおりましたら
設定方法を教えて頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

テレビ側が対応していないと思われます。
参考にされた記事にはリフレッシュレート15Hzとありますが、使用されているテレビでは未サポートです。

> I have managed to get 3840 x 2160 (4k x 2k) at 15Hz

[アクオストップ 製品ラインアップ US45ライン LC-50US45 外観・仕様](http://www.sharp.co.jp/aquos/products/lc50us45_spec.html)

> (注16) 480i,480p,1080i,720p（30/60Hz）,1080p（24/30/60Hz）,3840×2160p（24/30/60Hz）入力対応。

15Hzをサポートしているテレビ・モニターを入手して試してみましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございました。

リフレッシュレート15Hzにテレビが対応していないことが原因だと理解できました。